# Задача питон. Выдает ошибку EOF readline

Tags: python, python-3.x

. Вводится слово в переменную tp. Если это слово RECT, то следует объявить функцию с именем get_sq с двумя параметрами, вычисляющую площадь прямоугольника и возвращающую вычисленное значение. (На экран она ничего не должна выводить, только возвращать значение).
Если же введенное слово не RECT (любое другое), то объявляется функция с тем же именем get_sq, с одним параметром для вычисления площади квадрата (формула: a*a). Вычисленное значение возвращается функцией. (Она также ничего не выводит на экран).
Примечание: в программе должна быть задана только одна функция с именем get_sq в зависимости от введенного слова. Вызывать функцию не нужно, только объявлять.

```
Sample Input:
RECT
Sample Output:
10

tp = input().strip()

if tp == 'RECT':
    def get_sq(a, b):
        return a * b
else:
    def get_sq(a):
        return a * a

x , y = map(int, input().split())
print(get_sq(x, y))


 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 8, in <module>
    x,y = map(int, input().split())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Итого в остатке: код не соответствует тексту задачи.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_sq(a, b):
    return a * b

tp = input().strip()
x, y = map(int, input().split())
if not tp == 'RECT':
    y = x
print(get_sq(x, y))
```